# Xcode- uploading app to iOS device through SFTP

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

Hi I'm trying to upload an app to my iPad, (iOS 5.1) - Jailbroken,

Its a network search app, I'm using private API's and as I understand I need to put the build version of my app on the devices `/Applications` folder!

(lets say I have the process figured out, using cyberduck)

So far so good, everything works !

But each time I update code on my app, which files do I need to replace ? 
only the ones in the `/Applications` directory or also the ones at `/User/Applications/`. . . ? 
atm each time i update my code it seems the code won't update until I restart the device

before i restart I get the following error, through Xcode:

> A system application with the given bundle identifier is already
>   installed on the device   and cannot be replaced.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, not all private API's require administrative privileges; i.e. Apple80211 functions do though (in my case).

When uploading your application to the root folder

- Build the application for Archiving: (Release Build)
- Navigate to default build path
- /Users/"user"/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"name of app"/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/
- the build file is in the above dir,  "ApplicationName.app"
- upload this file into the root applications directory /Application
- (NOT TO /Private/Var/Mobile/Application)
- Use SSH to access iOS Device's File Directory
- Use SFT Protocol for file transfer - (CyberDuck is a good software)

Normally pressing the "run" button in Xcode will install the App at /Var/mobile/applications directory, however, if Xcode detects the app already exists at /Applications, then it simply uses the latter.

Thus: When you update your code . . . .
- You must create a new build ! (as described above) 
- Delete the folder "ApplicationName" from /Applications 
- and place your (new) updated build (ApplicationName.app) into the /Applications dir

Stumbler, is an excellent example to try the above steps; Stumbler uses the Apple80211 functions which require the application to be within /Applications; make slight changes to the code and try the above steps . . . .
Code available at: http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/

Hope this help some one along the way !

Taski

Comment: I think you basically said what I said in my answer, but you said it in a slightly confusing way.  You **cannot** run your app directly from Xcode if it's installed in `/Applications`.  As you say in your answer, *"Delete the previous build folder from /Applications ..."*.  Well, if you delete the install in `/Applications`, then you no longer have it in two places, so of course there's no conflict, right?  And, yes, you can run from Xcode, but if your app requires being outside the sandbox to run *correctly*, then you'll be able to debug, but your app won't work right.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use the term *"administrative privileges"*, because on a BSD system, that sounds like it's just about having `root` access.  It's more complicated than that.  Some private APIs do require the app to run as `root`.  Some private APIs do not require running as the `root` user, but do require having access to the `mobile` user's files that are outside the normal sandbox, that `/var/mobile/Applications` apps have.  Other private APIs require granting *entitlements* to the app to work correctly.  So, there's multiple levels of privileges, and you get them in different ways.

Comment: Finally, Xcode is not really *"making a copy"* of your app in `/var/mobile/Applications`.  It's installing it there, and only there.  It's not a copy.  I don't want to sound like I'm nitpicking, I just want to make sure you (and others) understand what you're seeing.

Comment: i'm very confused now guys ! ! !

I delete previous builds from /Application, ONLY to replace it with a newer build (updated code for instance) - I've been running it from within Xcode, and it works this way 

When i drag drop my build project, I drop it in, /Applications, and I see that the files in /var/mobile/Applications updates respectively . . . .

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding your responses.  Can you **edit** your answer here, and clearly list the **order** in which you are doing these things?  When are you deleting the app from /Applications?  When you say "drop in /Applications", do you mean that you SFTP it to /Applications?  You understand that when you press the **Run** button in Xcode, at that time, it *installs* the app into /var/mobile/Applications?

Comment: @Nate - Done, I've been playing with this many times now : so I'm very sure of the steps . . . these work !

Answer (score 4):

Just because you are using private APIs doesn't mean that you always need to install the app in `/Applications`.  It depends on *which* private APIs, and what you're trying to do.  System applications, and apps distributed through Cydia, would generally be installed in `/Applications`. Normal 3rd-party App Store apps (ours) get installed under `/var/mobile/Applications` (`/User/Applications` is a link to `/var/mobile/Applications`, so those two are the same location).

So, by default, Xcode does not install apps in /Applications.  It would install apps somewhere under `/var/mobile/Applications`.

If you manually put your app in `/Applications`, and then try to build and run it again from Xcode, Xcode will see the version in `/Applications/MyAppName.app`, and even though it's trying to install to `/var/mobile/Applications/*/MyAppName.app`, it will recognize a conflict, based on the bundle identifier (which is specified in the app's Info.plist file).

So, you can't have an app with the same bundle identifier installed both in `/Applications` and `/var/mobile/Applications`.  I would pick which place you want it.

If you want your app in `/Applications`, then use a script to install it (for example, with SFTP).  If you want your app in `/var/mobile/Applications`, then you can build **and run** directly from Xcode.

As to needing a restart, that shouldn't be necessary.  You may need to `ssh` into your device, and issue the `uicache` command:

```bsh
ssh mobile@iphone
uicache
```

or

```bsh
ssh root@iphone
su mobile -c uicache
```

to get SpringBoard to recognize a newly installed app.  That's not necessary if you run directly from Xcode, but if you build from Xcode, then run a (SFTP) install script, then you may need to run `uicache`.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** I didn't get into the issue of writing custom post-build scripts/steps to be invoked from within Xcode.  So, when I refer to running from Xcode in the above answer, I'm referring to the default mode in which Xcode works.

Comment: @nycynik, I don't know **everything** that `uicache` does, but it seems to tell SpringBoard to refresh its list of the installed apps.  I would assume it iterates through the install locations (e.g. /var/mobile/Applications and /Applications) and looks for apps, then reads their Info.plist files, to detect the app's display name, and icon.  It then updates the display of your home screen.

Comment: @nate thank you very much for just the sheer detail of your explanations, But heres what I have found in the answer below